# How to log SOAP requests in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, axis, coldfusion-8

We would like to know which IP called our CF8 SOAP webservice (powered by Axis 1) and which method are being invoked. IIS log only shows POST from local IP.  How can I enable logging for published SOAP webservices?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function, isSoapRequest, that determines if a CFC is being called as a web service. You could use that and if true, then log.

Comment: henry, is there an x-forwarded-for header in the cgi scope?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, Henry, There is no such logging, built-into CF.

I thought by your subject you were referring to outgoing web service calls (from within CFML), which since 9.0.1 are indeed logged (whether you do a CFINVOKE or CFOBJECT call), including the URL (but not the method) in the webservice.log.

But you want to log incoming calls to CFCs serving as web services, and there is no built-in logging for those. Not even in good ol' FusionReactor (which logs many things CF does not).

This would be a good thing, so I'd suggest you file a feature request. Until then, it would be incumbent upon you to do your own logging within your CFCs, using CFLOG to capture that useful info you seek.

You may even want to write it up as a method that others could reuse (and who knows, if you look around, maybe you'll find someone else having already done it).